Error generating chart: Image.parseExpression: Expression contains undeclared variables: [max] for vci, and tci
I have a problem creating the chart and there is error message expression undeclared variables
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[47.34712015582472, 32.60061492881615],
          [47.34712015582472, 30.598309169533678],
          [50.68147074176222, 30.598309169533678],
          [50.68147074176222, 32.60061492881615]]], null, false),
    imageCollection2 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A2"),
    imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2");

Map.centerObject(geometry);

var time_start = '2001', time_end = '2024'

var ndvi = imageCollection.select('NDVI')
.filterDate(time_start, time_end);

//print(ndvi)

var temp = imageCollection2.select('LST_Day_1km')
.filterDate(time_start, time_end);

//print(temp)

//vci: vegetation condition index
//ndvi, ndvi_min, ndvi_max
//vci = (ndvi - ndvi_min)/(ndvi_max - ndvi_min)

var ndvi_min = ndvi.min()
var ndvi_max = ndvi.max()

// temporal function to convert data into monthly format

function temporal_collection(collection, start, count,interval, unit){
  var seq = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var origin_date = ee.Date(start);
  return ee.ImageCollection(seq.map(function(i){
    var start_date = origin_date.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i),unit);
    var end_date = origin_date.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), unit);
    return collection.filterDate(start_date, end_date).mean()
    .set('system:time_start', start_date.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', end_date.millis())
  }))
}

//monthly ndvi image collection

var ndvi_monthly = temporal_collection(ndvi, time_start, 276, 1, 'month');

print(ndvi_monthly);

var vci = ndvi_monthly.map(function(img){
  var index = img.expression('(ndvi-min) / (max-min)',
  {'ndvi': img.select('NDVI'), 'min':ndvi_min,'max':ndvi_max})
  return index.rename('VCI')
  .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
  });
  
// tci: thermal condition index
// lst_max, lst_min
// tci = (max- lst)/ (max - min)

var temp_max = temp.max();
var temp_min = temp.min();

var temp_monthly = temporal_collection(temp, time_start, 276, 1, 'month');
print(temp_monthly);

var tci = ndvi_monthly.map(function(img){
  var index = img.expression('(max - lst) / (max-min)',
  {'mac': temp_max, 'min': temp_min,'lst':img.multiply(0.02)})
  return index.rename('TCI')
  .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
  });

var modis_indices = vci.combine(tci);

//vhi: vegetation heatlh index
//vci = 0.5 * vci + (1-0.5) * tci

var drought = modis_indices.map(function(img){
  var vhi = img.expression('0.5 * vci + (1 - 0.5) * tci',{
    'vci': img.select('VCI'), 'tci':img.select('TCI')
    }).rename('VHI')
    return img.addBands(vhi)
    .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
});

print(
  ui.Chart.image.series(drought, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(),
  1000, 'system:time_start')
  )


You have a typo in the dictionary passed to the tci expression.  You called it 'mac', not 'max'.

Thank you very much.
